# AlarmManager does not start the service

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager to start a service in specific hour, which should send a notification when called. But it seems that AlarmManager does not work when the app is killed or stopped in background.

My code:
(MainActivity)

```
    Intent iNotifikace = new Intent(context, Notifikace.class);
    PendingIntent notifikace = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iNotifikace, 0);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time));

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, notifikace);
```

Service:

```
public class Notifikace extends IntentService {


public Notifikace() {
    super("Notifikace");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


}@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Thread Name");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Notifikace.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("Notification")
                            .setContentText("NotificationText");
                    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(002, mBuilder.build()); stopSelf();


    return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }}
```

BootReceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String time = sharedPref.getString("pref_time", "16");

    Intent iNotifikace = new Intent(context, Notifikace.class);
    PendingIntent notifikace = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, iNotifikace, 0);
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time));



    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, kontrolaZastupovani);
}}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".Notifikace"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

        />




</application>
```

Thanks for help and have a nice day!

Comment: KontrolaZastupovani.class is this broadcast receiver ? is yes please put the source code

Comment: I suggest to use GcmNetworkManager and not the (outdated) AlarmManager, as this class makes use of the new JobScheduler in API21+ and also works in all lower APIs and it has its own service base class that gets called properly, including BOOT_COMPLETED (if you have the permission set in your manifest file).

Comment: several things to be aware of: 1. Runtime Permissions if you develop or execute on marshmallow and above:https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html 2. Some devices restrict to start an app after boot, even if you put permissions inside. Example on Huawei devices your app must be protected inside the telephone manager app. 3. Be aware of doze mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: For RuntimePermissions: Even if you develop on a lower API than marshmallow, if you execute your app on a device with marshmallow and above, it´s possible that your permissions get restricted by default and you have to enable it manually.

Comment: @Grisgram Please, `AlarmManager` is not outdated. Often abused? Maybe. ***|||*** SWDEV, did you register all the services and receivers in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: GcmNetworkManager seems to be too much work and overloads the application only for fire alarm. It´s not intended for execute only alarms: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager

Comment: As you are using `IntentService` you must implement the `super()` call if you override other methods than `onHandleIntent()` . That´s stated out in the API: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. That means, in your `onStartCommand` you have to return: `return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);` Or you have to implement that work in `onHandleIntent()` instead of inside `onStartCommand()`

Comment: ...and on an IntentService, you must not call `stopSelf();`